# How i can get back reserved amount for verify identity procedure?

Tags: polkadot, identify

in February i was got true status with verify identity procedure.

Now end of March but reserved amount ( ~ 20 DOT ) still locked.

Could tell me please how I can unlock it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DOTs are reserved for having an on-chain identity and you can get them back when you clear the identity info https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-identity#clearing-and-killing-an-identity

To get your account identity verified, you would have used the registrar service which is availed with a fee (not a deposit) https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-identity#current-registrars